# How can I convert coordinate accelerations to proper acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, acceleration, coordinate-systems

I need to calculate what an accelerometer would feel from the motions from a simulation. The simulation only gives position data in a global reference frame. How can I convert this global positioning data to what an accelerometer would measure?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to calculate. Do you need the acceleration measured in an accelerating reference frame given the acceleration in an inertial reference frame?

Comment: Are you asking about correcting for the rotation of the earth, or how to get the global acceleration from the position data, or something else?